# How can I inject and use multiple datasources dynamically in Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have these profiles, uat-nyc, uat-ldn.
uat-nyc datasource is oracle and uat-ldn is mysql server
This configuration is setup in application-uat-nyc.yml and application-uat-ldn.yml

I have below configuration class

```
    @Profile({"uat-nyc", "uat-ldn"})
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationPropeties(DatSourceProperties.class)
    public class DataSourceConfig{

    private DataSourceProperties properties; // server, username, password are set here
    

    DataSource getDataSource(){// gets datasource based on profiles}
    
    }
```

if my application is run with spring.profiles.active: uat-nyc,uat-ldn will it create two datasources, ?

one with configuration from uat-nyc and another from uat-ldn

I have a function below, in this function, I am getting data from third-party service, and depending on ldn or nyc , I need to persist into ldn or nyc database. How can I make the below if else section dynamic? How can I get respective datasources i.e ldn and nyc in the if else section in below getProducts method?

```
 class Product{
       String name;
       int price;
       int region;
    }
    
     @Component
     Class ProductLoader{

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        
         public ProductLoader(DataSource ds){
            
                 jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
         }
    
        public void getProducts(){
             List<Product> products = // rest service to get products
             if(Product product : product){
                          if(product.getRegion().equals("LONDON"){
                            //write to LONDON datbase
                           // How can I get ldn datasource here?
                          }
                          if else(product.getRegion().equals("NewYork"){
                               //write to NewYork datbase
                               How can I get NewYork datasource here? 
                          }
                          else{
                               // Unknown location
                          }
             }

 
    }
}
```

Question -

1. if my application is run with spring.profiles.active: uat-nyc,uat-ldn will it create two datasources, ?
2. How can I inject the datasources dynamically into ProductLoader and use specific datasource for  ldn and nyc

Answer (score 0):

At the first time you need to tell spring you gonna use two datasource will be managed by context spring. use @Bean on @Configuration class then use @Autowired to declareing vars managed by spring.

you could use @Qualifier to choose and qualify your beans

```java
@Configuration
public class ConfigDataSource {


    // example for dataSource
    
    @Bean("dataSourceWithPropOnCode") // this name will qualify on @autowired
    public DataSource dataSourceWithPropOnCode() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url("").password("").username("").driverClassName("").build();
    }

    @Bean("dataSourceWithPropFromProperties")  // this name will qualify on @autowired
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.yourname-datasource") // this is the name for the prefix for datasource on .properties settings
    public DataSource dataSourcePostgres() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    // example for jdbctemplate
    
    @Bean("jdbcTemaplateWithPropFromProperties")  // this name will qualify on @autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplatePostgres(@Qualifier("dataSourceWithPropFromProperties") DataSource dataSource) {
     return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    
    @Bean("jdbcTemaplateWithPropOnCode")  // this name will qualify on @autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplatePostgres(@Qualifier("dataSourceWithPropOnCode") DataSource dataSource) {
     return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    
    
}
```

settings on properties

```
spring.datasource.yourname-datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.yourname-datasource.jdbcUrl=${spring.datasource.yourname-datasource}
spring.datasource.yourname-datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.yourname-datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.yourname-datasource.driver-class-name=your.driver
```

using on services

```java
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemaplateWithPropFromProperties")
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;
    
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemaplateWithPropOnCode")
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2;
    
    @Qualifier("dataSourceWithPropOnCode")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource1;
    
    private DataSource dataSource2;
    
    public someContructorIfYouPrefer(@Qualifier("dataSourceWithPropFromProperties") @Autowired private DataSource dataSource2){
        this.dataSource2 = dataSource2;
    }
```